# What community to ask "law-ish" questions

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

**I've got a question I want to ask, but I'm not sure what community to ask it in.**

I'm aware that Stack sites are not geographically restricted, so asking a question that has a "legally does X" formula, causes some issues since the question becomes geographically locked, and no-one want's to chuck down an opinion about anything 'legally'.

So for this meta question, I have my question that I wanted to ask: *"When I get a shipment from China, and it's delivered to me in England by Fedex, when do I become bound OR do I become bound by Fedex's Terms and Conditions, or Terms of Carriage - I've received a shipment, they want some "service fees" to be paid on the delivery, but I don't believe I'm responsible for those fees since I'm not the sender."

So that's the question I want to ask, but I don't know where, or IF it's a suitable question for any of the stackexchange network.

Is there a way to make it a suitable question?  Or is this the kind of question I should take to somewhere like "Quora".  Obviously I like coming to Stack Exchange, but I'm not sure if it's the 'right' or even possible to ask a 'geographically restricted and "legal-eez" question'

Comment: You are responsible for any customs fees or taxes payable on your parcel. See [Tax and customs for goods sent from abroad - GOV.UK](https://www.gov.uk/goods-sent-from-abroad)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should take it either to [Law](https://law.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange or to [Travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange. I think Law is your best bet, because they deal with "legal-ish" stuff a lot. If it's not well received there, you can flag it for mod attention so they can migrate it to Travel.

Comment: I can't see Travel liking this question, as the problem is neither specific to traveling or commonly faced by travelers. [Expats](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/) might be somewhat better, but even then I don't think it's a particularly good fit.